Highlight partial match in a different Sheet using Conditional Formatting
Test worksheet is here - Link to Sheet
I have in Page 1, Col A, a list of warehouse locations, and in Page 2, I have "prefixes" as an identifier range in Columns A and C (to apply a new conditional formatting rule for each range check)
I need it to highlight Col A in Page 1, if it contains anywhere matches to a lookup for text in Page 2 (Col A would be rule 1, Col C rule 2)
I used this formula and got good results, but I'm unsure on how to use it to reference a different page (I wondered if I can use Indirect to help reference an external range, but cannot figure out where to apply it)
=IF(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH($F2, FILTER($C$2:$C, $C$2:$C <> ""))), TRUE) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
(edit -- ps I did a late edit of how the formula worked referencing the same page, but I can't for the life of me get it to work referencing a different page)

As of the time of this comment, Google Sheet's Conditional Formatting's custom formula canNOT refer to a different Sheet. You will need to include whatever you want within the same Sheet, such as by making a helper column

Use indirect() to access the other sheet.


Here's one approach you may test out using indirect() to refer to a different tab within Conditional Formatting:
=regexmatch(A2,textjoin("|",1,indirect("Page 2!A$2:A")))


